# NameError: name 'self' is not defined after using eval()

Tags: python-3.x, eval

I am trying to save some copy-paste while defining my buttons and other things in my main class through `eval()`. I know `eval()` is supposed to be handled with care, but here I give the commands within my code. Here's the code that creates an error:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
            [...]
            Schaltpunkte=["Aussen1","Innen1","Innen2","Innen","Alle"]
            for Schaltpunkt in Schaltpunkte:
                 eval("self.ui.Button_"+Schaltpunkt+"Laden.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ladeZeitschaltung("+Schaltpunkt+"))")
```

The error I get once I clicked the button:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I had this idea, because `eval()` works very well inside another function:

```
Programm = eval("self.ui.Box_"+Schaltpunkt+"Programm.value()")
```

Does someone have any advice? Or is it simply wrong to connect buttons with actions through such code? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your `lambda` function is not aware of `self`.
Try to define a symbol table mentioning `self`, and give it to `eval()`:

```
symbols = {"self": self}
eval("lambda x: self.foo(x)", symbols)
```